# Informing div to look like boxes without distrubing Grids

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Greetings i am kinda new to boostrap, Anyhow, I am trying to Create is, Boxes to look like this (right side):

[image: Here]

And so far i got nothing. i used padding but it mess up my grid system, what i did was give a `col-sm-8` for picture side and a `col-sm-4` for boxes however it is where it gets tricky it always mess my grid system. this is my html. could you help me out a little bit?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <img src="xxxx" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div style="background-color: grey; padding: 25px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">
                    Oven
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div style="background-color: grey; padding: 25px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">
                    Cookers
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div style="background-color: grey; padding: 25px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">
                    Microwave Ovens
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div style="background-color: grey; padding: 25px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">
                    Steamers
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div style="background-color: grey; padding: 25px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">
                    Cooker hoods
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div style="background-color: grey; padding: 25px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">
                    Hobs
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you talking about how they are being pushed down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `row` class, it's mandatory for nested rows/columns, so you can do this (go full page to see the result as you want) :

```css
.box {
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 10px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <img src="https://lorempixel.com/800/400/" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="box">
            Oven
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="box">
            Cookers
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="box">
            Microwave
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="box">
            Steamers
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="box">
            Cooker hoods
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="box">
            Hobs
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can read more about [grid nesting](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-nesting)